# Kubernetes get pods Crash

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a "logstash 6.5.4" pod using this file (cdn_akamai.yml) in machines with 16G of memory and 8 vCPUS

```
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: cdn-akamai-pipe
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cdn-akamai-pipe
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
      hostname: cdn-akamai-pipe
      containers:
      - name: cdn-akamai-pipe
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
          requests:
            memory: "1Gi"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9600
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.5.4
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cdn-akamai-pipe-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/cdn_akamai.conf
          subPath: cdn_akamai.conf
        - name: logstash-jvm-options-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config/jvm.options
          subPath: jvm.options
        - name: pipeline-config
          mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config/pipelines.yml
          subPath: pipelines.yml
        command:
        - logstash
      volumes:
      - name: cdn-akamai-pipe-config
        configMap:
          name: cdn-akamai-pipe
      - name: logstash-jvm-options-config
        configMap:
          name: logstash-jvm-options
      - name: pipeline-config
        configMap:
          name: pipeline-akamai

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cdn-akamai-pipe
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: cdn-akamai-pipe
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9600
    targetPort: 9600
    name: logstash
```

And using the next commands

```
kubectl create configmap logstash-jvm-options --from-file jvm.options
kubectl create configmap cdn-akamai-pipe --from-file cdn_akamai.conf
kubectl create configmap pipeline-akamai --from-file pipelines.yml
kubectl create -f cdn_akamai.yml
```

where the files are

```
Data  
====
pipelines.yml: 
----
- pipeline.id: main
  path.config: "/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/cdn_akamai.conf


Data
====
jvm.options:
----
-Xms800m
-Xmx800m
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true
-Djruby.jit.threshold=0
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom

Data
====
cdn_akamai.conf:
----
input {stdin{}}
output {stdout{}}
```

But I get Error or CrashLoopBackOff as

```
cdn-akamai-pipe-74c64757b9-t4k2f   0/1     Error     7          12m
```

I had running a [hello word pod](https://github.com/paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes) to verify if my cluster is ok, and this pod run perfectly.

Could you help me, please? Is there any problem with my volumes, service, syntax, Do you see anything?

Comment: Can you use this command `kubectl describe deployment <name_of_deployment>` and add a screen to your post? We will see why there is an error.

Comment: Add also output of `kubectl logs -p cdn-akamai-pipe-74c64757b9-t4k2f`